# Application Insights Exception Rate Alert, Strange results

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I've created an alert for exception rate. Looking at the graph on the alert, I seem to have a constant exception rate of just over 1 exception per second. However, when I look at Metrics, or look in the analysis tool, I can't find these exceptions. Can anyone explain where they're coming from and which metric I need to look at to find them?

[image: Alert Configuration]

[image: Exceptions]

Answer (score 0):

OK. I should have tried harder before asking the question!

The exception/sec performance counter counts both handled and unhandled exceptions. Here's the documentation:

#### # of Exceps Thrown / Sec

Displays the number of exceptions thrown per second. This includes both .NET exceptions and unmanaged exceptions that are converted into .NET exceptions.
  For example, an HRESULT returned from unmanaged code is converted to an exception in managed code.
  This counter includes both handled and unhandled exceptions. It is not an average over time; it displays the difference between the values observed in the
  last two samples divided by the duration of the sample interval. This counter is an indicator of potential performance problems if a large (>100s) number of exceptions are thrown.